# Cambiar de color del resultado

Tags: javascript

La idea es un programa que le añades dos números y te saca los pares o impares que hay entre ellos. Y me gustaría que los números se pueda cambiar con el input de type=color pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo ni si quiera sé si se podría hacer.

```js
function cargar() {
    a=document.getElementById("numero1");
    b=document.getElementById("numero2");
    a=parseInt(a);
    b=parseInt(b);
    ventana=document.getElementById("resultados");
    limpiar();
}
function pares(a,b) {
    
    a=parseInt(a);
    b=parseInt(b);
    limpiar();
    if(b<a) {
        x=a; 
        a=b;
        b=x;
    }    
        c=0;
        for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
        {
            
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                c++;
                ventana.innerHTML=ventana.innerHTML+" "+i;
                if(c==10)
                {
                    c=0;
                    ventana.innerHTML=ventana.innerHTML+"<br>";
                }
            }
        }    
}
function limpiar()
{
    ventana.innerHTML="";
}
function impares(a,b) {

    a=parseInt(a);
    b=parseInt(b);
    limpiar();
    if (b<a) {
        x=a; 
        a=b;
        b=x;
    }
        c=0;
        for(i=a;i<=b;i++) {
            if (i%2-1==0) {
            c++
            ventana.innerHTML=ventana.innerHTML+" "+i;
            if(c==10) {
                c=0;
                ventana.innerHTML=ventana.innerHTML+"<br>";
                }
            }
        }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <title>Examen js</title>
</head>
<body onload=cargar()>
    <div>
        <label for="numero1">Introduce Primer Numero:
            <input type="number" step="1" id="numero1"></label>
        <br>
        <label for="numero2">Introduce Ultimo Numero:
            <input type="number" step="1" id="numero2"></label>
              <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="button" value="Numeros pares" onclick="pares(numero1.value,numero2.value)"></th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="Numeros impares" onclick="impares(numero1.value,numero2.value)"></th>
                    <th><input type="color" value="Color" onclick="colorDiv()"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5" ><input class="limpiar" type="button" value="limpiar" onclick="limpiar()"></th>
                </tr>
    
              </table>
    <div id="resultados" class="resultado">
        <p>resultados:</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Podrías explicarlo de manera más clara?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que con cambiar color te refieras al color de fondo, tal vez esto te sería útil:

- obtener el color seleccionado actualmente en tu entrada de selección de color
- remplazar el color del fondo de tu resultado

Esto lo haces respectivamente mediante:

```
  let selectedColor = document.getElementById("selectedColor").value;
  elementoHTML.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
```

Este sería un ejemplo más completo:

```js
let ventana = document.getElementById("resultados");

limpiar();

function cambiaColor() {
  let selectedColor = document.getElementById("selectedColor").value;
  ventana.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
  let complementario = 0xffffff ^ selectedColor;
  ventana.style.color = `#${complementario.toString(16)}`;
}

function imprimeValores(stra, strb, strPares) {
  a = parseInt(stra);
  b = parseInt(strb);
  limpiar();
  strPares === 'pares' ?
    pares(a, b) :
    impares(a, b);
}

function pares(a, b) {
  if (b < a) {
    x = a;
    a = b;
    b = x;
  }
  c = 0;
  for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      c++;
      ventana.innerHTML += ` ${i}`;
      if (c == 10) {
        c = 0;
        ventana.innerHTML += "<br>";
      }
    }
  }
}

function limpiar() {
  ventana.innerHTML = "";
}

function impares(a, b) {
  if (b < a) {
    x = a;
    a = b;
    b = x;
  }
  c = 0;
  for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    if (i % 2 - 1 == 0) {
      c++
      ventana.innerHTML += ` ${i}`;
      if (c == 10) {
        c = 0;
        ventana.innerHTML += "<br>";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="numero1">Introduce Primer Numero:
            <input type="number" step="1" id="numero1" value="0"></label>
  <br>
  <label for="numero2">Introduce Ultimo Numero:
            <input type="number" step="1" id="numero2" value="0"></label>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="button" value="Numeros pares" onclick="imprimeValores(numero1.value,numero2.value,'pares')"></th>
      <th><input type="button" value="Numeros impares" onclick="imprimeValores(numero1.value,numero2.value,'impares')"></th>
      <th><input id="selectedColor" type="color" value="#ffffff" onchange="cambiaColor()"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5"><input class="limpiar" type="button" value="limpiar" onclick="limpiar()"></th>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div id="resultados" class="resultado">
    <p id="campoResultados">resultados:</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso también me sirve, a lo mejor me exprese mal jejeje pero quería cambiar los números no el fondo pero muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho tu aporte gracias

Comment: @RaulMartinez para eso existe el botón de flecha hacia arriba junto a las preguntas y respuestas, para marcar las que te hayan sido útiles. Te recomiendo hacer el recorrido para aprender a sacarle más provecho a este sitio. Saludos.